# How to test the response body in PAW

Tags: paw-app

Is there a way to "test" the response body and check whether it contains a particular response, and provide visual feedback in the UI if it succeeds/fails?
Even better would be the ability to stop running the rest of the requests in the collection if one of the tests fails (in case it's a chain of requests)

Comment: Not yet unfortunately. This kind of tests, visual feedback, chained requests will be part of a larger update :)

Comment: Any vague idea of when that would be?  I have to make a choice between Postman and Paw, and prefer Paw, but I do need tests for that...

Comment: It's not gonna be in the super near future unfortunately! But be sure that when it comes, you'll be able to import your documents from other formats :)

Comment: @MichaMazaheri I hope you add it soon.

Comment: Hi @MichaMazaheri, has been tests added? Is it possible to create this feature as an extension? I'd like to try it. This request has been over an year now.

Comment: No we haven't added the tests… the Paw for Teams (Paw 3) update has taken us longer than expected. But we've made a workaround as an extension, if that can help you in the meantime https://blog.paw.cloud/posts/secret-path-to-paw-assertions/